# Find Routes not containing these subnets

Tags: routing, ip, ipv4, subnet

Let's say I have 1000 ranges and I would like to make routes that doesn't match these ranges, anyone has any particular tips or tools to share beside doing math ?

Example :
I have these ranges

13.64.0.0/11

13.104.98.192/27

.......

.......

I want to find the routes that doesn't match with these subnets,
for the first range, the routes would be

[image]

and for the second :

[image]

.......

.......

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry I still doesn't understand which real-world problem your try to tackle. A more specific route is always preferred over a more generic route; so really a 0.0.0.0/0 route can as well be used. Please explain what your problem is so we can help you with a real solution.

Comment: I'm trying to do split tunneling, I want a list of ranges not being routed through the tunnel, so I need a list of routes that doesn't match with these ranges.

Comment: We need more information. Please edit your question to include a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your comment:

> I'm trying to do split tunneling, I want a list of ranges not being
>   routed through the tunnel, so I need a list of routes that doesn't
>   match with these ranges.

you really don't need this list.

Routing works primarily by selecting the more specific route first.

So in a split tunneling scheme:

- you have a default (0.0.0.0/0) route that points to your Internet Gateway.
- you have more specific routes that point to the VPN tunnel interface.

All traffic that doesn't match the specific routes will use the default route.

Simple example:

- Home LAN internal network 192.168.0.0.24; gateway 192.168.0.1
- Remote network connected through VPN with networks 172.16.0.0/20 and 10.0.0.0/12, interface ppp0
- You must connect to another network which use 10.0.10.0/24, second VPN connection interface ppp1

You have the following forwarding (routing) table:

```
0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.0.1
172.16.0.0/20 via ppp0
10.0.0.0/12 via ppp0
10.0.10.0/24 via ppp1
```

Then:

- a packet to 4.5.6.7 will goes through 192.168.0.1
- a packet to 10.0.10.1 will goes through ppp1
- a packet to 10.0.11.1 will goes through ppp0

Comment: In my case, all traffic except a list of ranges should go through the tunnel, and these 1000 ranges should go through the Home Internet, I want to exclude some ranges that consumes lot of Bandwidth from going through the tunnel